# How to unit test smart contracts

Tags: contract-design, testing, greeter

How are Ethereum contracts tested? I've seen [Truffle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle) which referrers to itself as an *Ethereum development framework*. Are there any other frameworks and what is their level of maturity? Is there a de facto standard framework used by most contract developers?

How would one go about testing the Greeter contract (https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/) for example?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Via a Framework

There are currently four primary frameworks available that can facilitate writing unit tests for your contracts.  Listed in order of Github stars as of 2016-01-25.

> Disclaimer: I'm the author of the Populus testing library.

### Embark

- website: https://iurimatias.github.io/embark-framework/
- written in: javascript
- tests: javascript via Mocha

This is the framework with the widest adoption.

### Truffle

- website: https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle
- written in: javascript
- tests: Mocha/Chai

### dapple

- website: https://github.com/NexusDevelopment/dapple
- written in: javascript
- tests: Solidity

### Populus

- website: http://populus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- written in: python
- tests: py.test

## Roll your own

You can also roll your own testing framework pretty easily by leveraging either [ethereumjs-vm](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm) or [pytester](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum) depending on whether you prefer javascript or python.

Comment: Populus looks cool. I'll also give it a try.

Comment: By all means let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: Do any of these frameworks allow systematic  testing of the effect of out of Gas exceptions? (I'm thinking that some kind of montecarlo style approach where you check invariants against lots of scenarios might be useful)

Comment: "Do any of these frameworks allow systematic testing of the effect of out of Gas exceptions?"

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this.  I know that with Populus you can test this by seeing that a `TransactionError` exception is raised as well as verifying that the `gasUsed` value from the transaction receipt is 100% of the provided gas.

Comment: There's also an option to write UTs in Go, using statically compiled bindings (i.e. code completion) from the .sol files: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native-DApps:-Go-bindings-to-Ethereum-contracts#blockchain-simulator. I've not found very much documentation on this approach though, would be interested in what others have found.

Comment: Truffle now has more than twice the number of stars as Embark.

Answer (score 1):

## Brownie

One of the best blockchain development framework written in Python. It supports native `pytest` which is able to run unit as well as integration tests.

The whole info on how to write and perfrom proper testing:

https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests-pytest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

**Waffle**

This is another popular testing library. It has support for TypeScript and works well with HardHat.

https://github.com/EthWorks/Waffle

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer you a link to these instructions that had helped me personally.

It shows the basics of testing smartContracts by using both Solidity and JavaScript. (You pick your favourite)

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-test-ethereum-smart-contracts-35abc8fa199d

Hope it helps you too.