# Can I use EthereumJS testrpc with ethjsonrpc (python) to test my contract localy?

Tags: json-rpc, python, testrpc, ethereumjs

As far as I understand **EthereumJS** can simulate a client on a simulated blockchain and provide **RPC interface** (hope I'm  using the right words). Does it mean I can interact with this client (and with my contract in simulated blockchain) with **ethjsonrpc**?

Related:

- [How to unit test smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/607/)
- [A 101 Noob Intro to Programming Smart Contracts](https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/a-101-noob-intro-to-programming-smart-contracts-on-ethereum-695d15c1dab4#.u7afcvln1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes since testrpc provides exactly a Remote Procedure Call interface you can use EthJsonRpc as a client library to interface with the simulated blockchain.
Just fire up testrpc in a console and it should work. I use testrpc together with truffle and it should be no different for a Python based client.

Comment: It works well, but I have another issue now: [Cannot catch every event (logs) from contract - catch a couple of random events instead](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7935/cannot-catch-every-event-logs-from-contract-catch-a-couple-of-random-events)