# Transaction to deploy a contract still pending?

Tags: contract-deployment

I made a sample smart contract and wanted to deploy it.
I used mist wallet to do that and everything seems to be ok except the [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd09b3d685b6ba435c07c93022027c5d356e7853e094db6ff2d2ae6419f3e6266) is still in "pending" mode.

Can you hightlight common practices for deploying a smart contract and common issues?

Comment: How much did you attempt to pay as a fee? insufficient fees can hinder transactions from being accepted. If you can see you transaction on etherscan it should be known to their node.

Comment: I had to wait around 24 hours to see the transaction actually applied. Until then it was in a pending state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, the time taken to get a smart contract deployed has no difference compared to the time taken for a transaction to be mined, since deploying a contract itself is a transaction. Hence the gas price you define matter when getting a priority in the pending transaction queue.

**Probably the reason behind the latency should be the low gas price when compared to the current network status, in your case as well.**

You may refer [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16428/does-gas-limit-have-any-bearing-on-transaction-mining-time).

> Can you hightlight common practices for deploying a smart contract and
>   common issues?

What you are referring here is the moment of sending it to the blockchain, it's all about transactions. But if you consider the development as well, thses aspects of [unit testing](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/607/how-to-unit-test-smart-contracts), [testing](https://medium.com/etherereum-salon/eth-testing-472c2f73b4c3),[securing](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6204/writing-secure-smart-contracts-in-solidity)  are important.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a updated (downloaded) blockchain to deploy a contract. The time it takes to deploy is the time it takes to be included in a block, which is mainly decided by the gas-price you are willing to pay and how full the blocks are.

Normal (as of 2017) is ~5-10 gwei per gas in order to get included within the first 1-5 min. I see you paid 3 gwei which might be a reason for the delay if there were network congestion at the same time.